# Interpolation using median in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that identifies the change in length of something over time, being able to fill the gaps when that data is seemingly missing.

In Hive, it'd look something like this:

`floor(percentile(cast(book_length as BIGINT), 0.5)) over (partition by book order by read_timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 20 PRECEDING AND 20 FOLLOWING)`

in bigquery (legacy) i imagine it'd look something like this:

`NTH(50, QUANTILES(book_length, 101)) OVER (PARTITION BY book order by read_timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 20 PRECEDING AND 20 FOLLOWING)`

however I get the error `Unrecognized is not currently supported as an analytic function`.

Any thoughts? I might be overcomplicating this... original hive solution was done very late at night :)

Answer (score 0):

NTH and QUANTILES aggregation functions (in BigQuery Legacy SQL) are not supported in Window Functions

Something like below should work but it is not what you need

```
SELECT 
  book,
  NTH(50, QUANTILES(book_length , 101)) as x
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY book
```

Check other function that ARE supported for Window / Analytic Functions
like NTH_VALUE, NTILE ...

Legacy SQL - [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions)
Standard SQL - [Analytic Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions)